# foreach in symfony 2

Tags: php, foreach

Having trouble working out how to get the last iterate row every 4 it puts in a  but i need to find the last one so I can make that do something

```
foreach( $gallery->getMedia() as $key => $media )
{
        if( ($key % 4 ) == 0 ) $html .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
        $url = $media->dir . '/' . $media->filename;

        $html .= sprintf( '<li><a href="#photo-%s" class="album_image_wrapper" id="photo_%s" title="%s" alt="%s" target="_blank" class="image-link" rel="slideshow"><div style="background-image: url(\'',
                $media->id ,
                $media->id ,
                $url,
                $gallery->name ,
                $media->id ,
                $this->generateThumbUrl( $url, array( 'width' => 100, 'height'=> 120, 'zoom' => true) ),
                $media->title,
                $galleryID  );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Symfony2 then you definitely shouldn't be rendering HTML content like this, you should be using the templating engine, [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

e.g. From a controller (I assume this is in a controller):

```
return $this->render('BundleName:ControllerName:view.html.twig', array(
    'gallery' => $gallery
);
```

Then in your `/path/to/BundleName/Resources/views/ControllerName/view.html.twig` template:

```
{% for key, media in gallery.media %}
    {% if loop.last %}
        {# Logic for the last iteration of the loop #}
    {% endif %}

    {% if loop.index % 4 == 0 %}
        {# Logic for every 4th iteration #}
    {% endif %}

    {# other code... #}

{% endfor %}
```